# Where are the docs for tasks.withType()?

Tags: gradle

Gradle is a well documented project, but when I search for the docs for `tasks.withType()`, I only find the [API docs](https://docs.gradle.org/2.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskCollection.html).

Isn't this an official part of Gradle?

Comment: If you can find the official API docs, why shouldn't this be an official part?

Comment: because I expected that this concept would be also explained in the general docs...

Comment: Gradle docs are one of the worst... at least for search purposes

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One of the fundamental concepts in Gradle is that everything is executed against a [Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) instance. Once you know that, you can work through the javadoc to find what you want. There's a bit of "magic" to be wary of too (a topic for another conversation) and also groovy syntax to understand .

So `tasks.withType(...)` can be looked up in the javadocs as `Project.getTasks().withType(...)`.

You'll notice that `Project.getTasks()` returns a `TaskCollection` (which you found in your googling)

*** edit ***

There's a mention [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html) in the docs which links to the `TaskContainer` javadocs

> A project is essentially a collection of Task objects. Each task performs some basic piece of work, such as compiling classes, or running unit tests, or zipping up a WAR file. You add tasks to a project using one of the create() methods on TaskContainer, such as TaskContainer.create(java.lang.String). You can locate existing tasks using one of the lookup methods on TaskContainer, such as TaskCollection.getByName(java.lang.String)

Comment: So, it seems that it is true that there are only API-Docs and no User-Docs. It seems that also books don't mention it... :-|

Comment: See my edit, there's a mention in the `Project` docs which links to `TaskContainer` javadocs