# Gradle's withType usage

Tags: gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Like [this other user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880994/where-are-the-docs-for-tasks-withtype), I have problems to understand the `withType` usage, example

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs.add("-Xbootclasspath/p:${file}")
}
```

... and differently from him, I have found official docs, as always, completely unuseful. Can you tell me what `withType` exactly does?

Comment: I am having a frustrating time-wasting task of figuring out what is wrong with my gradle script as well just like @Lore. The above was not working for me too. But, for strange reason this is compiling `tasks.withType<JavaCompile> { }` and I have not the foggiest idea why. I need to set options on my java compiler. If I had used the javac command line by now, I would have finished this task. Gradle is actually holding me back and making this process very painful. And, it's not that I don't understand Kotlin. I do. Gradle has proved as time consuming as Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It finds all defined tasks in the current project that are of given type. You can have multiple tasks named and configured differently, but sharing the same type (and implementation details).

E.g. there is one task type `JavaCompile` that is then added as two tasks in standard Java project: `compileJava` and `testCompileJava`.
More could be found in Gradle [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:configuring_tasks). The syntax you ask about will give you possibility to set common config for all such tasks.