# Gradle: provide `.java` files to compiler in deterministic order

Tags: java, gradle

I have cloned the same project twice on the same computer.

The output of `./gradlew --debug` contains a line that starts with

`[DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler] Compiler arguments:`

The compiler arguments differ for the two clones:  the `.java` files are provided in a different order.
How can I make the `.java` files appear in deterministic order?

(In theory, the order in which the files are provided should make no difference.  However, I am seeing differences between the two machines, I am debugging within the compiler, and using a deterministic order for the files will assist me in debugging.)

Answer (score 2):

Configure [JavaCompile](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html) tasks by adding similar code snippet to your project build.gradle file:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { compilationTask ->                                                                                                                                                                       
    compilationTask.source = compilationTask.source.sort()                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

For more information check [Where are the docs for tasks.withType()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880994/where-are-the-docs-for-tasks-withtype) on StackOveflow